# Is it possible to have duplicated folders on /home folder new partition as an error?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, home-directory

I move my home directory to it's own partition but I end with what it seems to be a duplicated home folders (there are 2 accounts admin and everyones account) I have "admin and everyones" folders and then I have in hide ".ecryptfs" inside I had again "admin and everyones" folder inside there is .encryptfs and .private inside each account cant read it's content as seems encrypted.

Which of both folders I'm able to delete the ones inside .encryptfs or the other showing in unhide mode "admin and everyones"?

It seems is duplicated as have the same file size.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true duplication, per se.

One of those views of the file (the encrypted ones that actually gets written to disk) is in `/home/.ecryptfs`.  The other ones (the decrypted ones) are just a virtual view presented by the kernel.  They don't take up any additional disk space.